# Browserify node_module usage / Google Translate Api

Tags: javascript, html, browserify, node-modules, google-translate

I have a simple problem about Browserify module usage. Let me explain;

As you know there is a free api about google translate which is "google-translate-api" in npm. I need to use it in browser so I have to convert it by using browserify. Everthing was cool for me at this point.

I had installed browserify and done my convert proccess. Its about 300kb file and I had check all node modules which is needed, were converted as well.

My problem is, when I have been using it, I got an error in my console:

**"Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../../package' "**

Its clear that it can not find module :) But I am new to use modules and etc.

**The module which I have converted by Browserify :**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-translate-api

My HTML code :

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Test</title>        
  </head>
<body>
        <script src="test.js"></script>            
    <script>

        translate('Ik spreek Engels', {to: 'en'}).then(res => {
        console.log(res.text);
        //=> I speak English 
        console.log(res.from.language.iso);
        //=> nl 
        }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        });
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

My test.js file which I have converted from google-translate-api module

[test.js](http://bahabilgin.com/test.js)

**snippet**

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="http://bahabilgin.com/test.js"></script>            
        <script>
            translate('Ik spreek Engels', {to: 'en'}).then(res => {
            console.log(res.text);
            //=> I speak English 
            console.log(res.from.language.iso);
            //=> nl 
            }).catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            });
        </script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to use https://unpkg.com/, it is much easier than browsify..

Comment: I had look up but I havent seen any example or usage.

Comment: Use this as a cdn url https://unpkg.com/google-translate-api@2.3.0/index.js

Comment: I had try and got an error.. Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: I think there is no umd build, so you can't use this on browser..  you have to use browsify..

Comment: I am using browserify, the original api is google-translate-api, I have converted and boundle it to test.js by using browserify